# Python 3 - query postgres db and manipulate results

Tags: python, postgresql, sms

I'm a newbie at programming. I'm trying to create a program that will extract data from a Postgres db, do a bit of formatting on it, and then push that data out through an SMS message. Using python 3, I can connect to and query the db, and I can also send out data through SMS. It's the tasks in between that I need help with!

Following is the stripped down code I'm using for the querying:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xxxxxxxxx' user='xxxxxxxx' host='xxxxxxxx' port='xxxxxx' password='xxxxxxxxx'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT ......")
```

From here, I can use the `cur.fetchall()` or `cur.fetchone()` to see the result. Now let's suppose I want to do something with that result. For example, format it (maybe it's a phone number and I want to strip out all non-numeric characters). How can I manipulate this data?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, I just started programming!

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to access those values?

Answer (score 1):

`cur.fetchall()` and `cur.fetchone()` return tuples (or a single tuple in the case of `fetchone()`) you can access a column value by index and store a row in a variable and manipulate it like any other variable, you could use regular expressions to strip non numeric chars:

```
import psycopg2
import re

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xxxxxxxxx' user='xxxxxxxx' host='xxxxxxxx' port='xxxxxx' password='xxxxxxxxx'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT id, phone FROM table")

result = cur.fetchone()  # Fetch first result
str_phone = result[1]  # Get the 2nd column (phone) value

only_numbers = re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', str_phone)  # Strip non numeric chars
```

Of course you could write this in a more compact way, without that extra var:

```
phone = re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', result[1])
```

And convert it to a number type with `int()` if that's what you are after:

```
phone = int(re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', result[1]))
```

Comment: So the fetchone() example above returns the first result. How would I get the 2nd, 3rd, etc.?

Comment: You can just iterate the cursor to get each row as a tuple, or use the `fetchmany()` or `fetchall()` cursor methods. Check the docs at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#fetch